# Ubuntu LTS 12.04 has suddenly become very slow for me today

Tags: 12.04, updates

I am using 12.04 lts release for past 4 months and was fine with it, until just now the OS is unresponsive in all the applications(browser, opening of folders etc).

Then i read some of the related posts here regarding updating Nvidia graphics driver. I checked my driver its Intel and not Nvidia.

Presently i am applying changes after installing through the update manager, but it seems the  application of changes is taking forever even for 21MB of update!!!
Along with that lts keep running slow!!?

Do i have any option to wait for these update to get applied? Will the response improves after update?

The only noticeable thing i noticed before my system gone bad was that update manager prompted me to install some update packages which will update to 12.04.2 from current 12.04.2?

Comment: Are you using only official sources or did you add any custom PPAs?

Comment: I would also try booting from a liveDVD or liveUSB and see if they work properly. Also I would check if there is a RAM failure (run memtest).

Comment: benchmark your hard disk (unless it's an SSD) and see if bad sectors or clusters are involved. If you are using an SSD check if the firmware of that disk is up to date.

Comment: check if your hard drive is full